# knative with eks fargate

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate, knative-serving

I am using knative serve with AWS eks, and using fargate as node. Now when I am deploying the sample application it is not provisioning ALB or NLB or CLB as ingress or service even though I have installed the load balancer controller on the cluster, but when I create simple(without knative) deployment with annotation it gives me the NLB or ALB as per the annotation. So how I can achieve the same with kntaive.

I am trying to use knative with eks and expecting if i can provision aws load balancer to the services to access it.